# Layout id has to be added again after its specified

Tags: android, layout

I have this very simple `layout`:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="70dp">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewBottom"
    style="@style/NLBTextAppearanceSmall"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:text="Information"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewTop"
    style="@style/NLBTextAppearance"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur condimentum tortor quis quam hendrerit, a rhoncus mauris porta. In at nisl et arcu consequat placerat. Integer in ipsum lectus. Proin elementum faucibus odio, in sodales dui tristique eget"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textViewBottom" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I don't understand why i have to do `@+id/textViewBottom` again in `android:layout_above of textViewTop;` after the `id` has been added already in `textViewBottom`.
If i remove the "+" sign from that line, the views overlap eachother. I never had issues with this before ...

Comment: Guys i rebooted my pc and cleared cache, this issue seems to be gone, i don't have to specifiy it twice anymore now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the app is built, it creates a file to reference all id added in your layouts. Then you can use these id to retrieve views or to place a view based on another one.

The `+id/` add the id to this list of references, when `id/` only use it.

You can't use a reference before it has been declared, so the first time should always be `+id/` even if it not on the view defined by the id.

If I use your example:

```
<!-- VIEW 1 -->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewBottom"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="#fff9e5"
    android:text="Information" />

<!-- VIEW 2 -->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewTop"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@id/textViewBottom"
    android:background="#e5ffe5"
    android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet" />
```

The `VIEW 1` declares the id `textViewBottom` so, when you want to position the `VIEW 2` above it, you just need to use `id` as `textViewBottom` has already be declared.

If you change the order of the views like that:

```
<!-- VIEW 2 -->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewTop"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textViewBottom"
    android:background="#e5ffe5"
    android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet" />


<!-- VIEW 1 -->
<TextView
    android:id="@id/textViewBottom"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="#fff9e5"
    android:text="Information" />
```

Now `VIEW 2` needs to declare `textViewBottom` in order to use it as it has never been declared before. Otherwise the view is not gonna be placed correctly. So now, when you want to add the id on the `VIEW 1` you don't need to do `+id/` as the id has already been declared.

Comment: finally someone with a decent answer. You are right i do not need to create +id/ again, there was something wrong with my android studio, after reboot i was able to remove the second +id and it worked fine

Comment: Yeah sometimes there are weird synchronisation/index issues. The other day I had to remove the entire `.idea` folder from my project as neither clearing Android Studio nor the project cache solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You are giving  `android:layout_above="@+id/textViewBottom` to make that `Textview` above the `TextView` named **textViewBottom**.

It's property of `RelativeLayout` Just go thorough `Relativelayout` and its basic properties to understand it clearly.

Comment: The id has been added in textViewBottom by doing @+id/textViewBottom, why do i have to do it twice? this isn't really an answer to my question

Comment: ya, see properties are different. you are specifying  android:id="@+id/textViewBottom" to give identification to TextView named textViewBottom and you are using property android:layout_above to make TextView textViewTop above it :)

Answer (score 1):

If you use `id` for a reference purpose in `RelativeLayout` then you only use `@id/` instead of  `@+id/` if that **id** already given to any `VIew`

That means your `R.java` file have already registered that `Id` that's why only need to use `@id/`